# Why is it called the Max Lange attack?

Tags: opening, terminology

Why is it called the *Max* Lange attack and not simply the Lange attack? After all, we don't have openings called the Richard Reti opening or the Wilhelm Steinitz defense or the Frank Marshall attack. Is the Max Lange the only opening with a first and last name?

Comment: Ruy Lopez. But it's still an interesting question, though it's going to be hard to get a non-speculative answer.

Comment: Ruy Lopez is his first name.  My guess is that he's not as well known.  You don't need to say the last name of Madonna, Cher, or little Richard.

Comment: **Warning**: this is pure speculation from my side, I have no idea if this played any role. If the opening were named 'Lange Attack', its German translation would be 'Lange Angriff'. This sounds very similar to the translation of 'long attack', which is 'langer Angriff'.

Comment: More speculation: "Max Lange" is reasonably short. Compare "Evgeny Sveshnikov" for example. On top of that, "Lange" would have to be present regardless, so the additional text is just "Max".

Comment: The use of the first might be a joke due to the double meaning of "Max."  I do like  Glorfindel's theory.

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't think so. Nobody would confuse a "Lange-Angriff" (hyphen!) with a "Langer Angriff", just as nobody seriously thinks that the "Caro-*Kann*-Verteidigung" has anything to do with a "Kanne" ("jug") or the verb "können" ("kann" in 3rd person sing.) - similar to the Marshall Attack, where generally people also know that is is named after a person, not a military rank.

Comment: @Annatar I'm not a native German speaker, but suppose a chess player (who does not know the Max Lange Attack) hears something like: "Der Spiel fängt an mit einem Lange Angriff". Wouldn't that be confusing?

Comment: @Glorfindel : No more than an English speaker would be confused by "Bird's Opening". -> "Huh, is this one named after the animal? But then the *'s* is a bit odd. Maybe it's a master's name..". A little *n* (Das Spiel fängt an mit einem lange**n** Angriff / mit einem Lange-Angriff) is all one needs to disambiguate.

Comment: @Annatar in writing, yes. Also the capital L would give it away. I mentioned *sounds* in my first comment but forgot to emphasize it. I know the pronunciation is still different, but that *r* often slips.

Comment: @Glorfindel Of course it is not impossible to confuse the two expressions. But that seems not to be a sufficient reason to add a first name, usually.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Closer example: The various "Schlechter Variation"s. In German, that's also only one letter off of "Schlechte Variante" ("Bad Variation"). Actually, you could even leave the "r" .. "Schlechter-Variante" can be translated to "Worse-Variation". Still, I have never seen the Carl added so far.

Comment: OK, there goes my theory...

Answer (score 1):

Well, they don't have an explicit protocol on whether to use the first name, the last name, or both the first and last name. Though admittedly, the Lange Attack sounds more right than the Max Lange attack.

There is a completely different story for how an opening gets its name. There are a couple openings that are named after people that didn't even play the opening or come up with the opening itself. Furthermore, there are openings named after animals or whatever; the Sicilian dragon, the Halloween gambit, the English opening, the French defense, the Hedgehog, the King's gambit, etc.

It might be based on the individual. They try to come up with a formal name of a variation based on the person's name, but to some people, it is more formal to use only the last name or the other way around (Grandmaster Tarjan instead of Grandmaster James or Grandmaster James Tarjan). On top of that, if you are lesser known or not famous, then it is considered more formal to use both the first and last name.

You have the Ruy Lopez, but not many other openings that use the first name. It is likely a result of the guy's preference. Again, an individual story for every opening, and it is cultural and normal to use only the last name, but there is ought to be a line that uses the first and last name too.

Comment: How did I overlook the Ruy Lopez. There is also the Ghulam Kassim Gambit 1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 g5 4.Bc4 g4 5.d4.